# Not able to extract text from *.doc file using subprocess library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm not able to extract the text from *.doc file

```
 res = subprocess.Popen(['antiword', filepath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                shell=True).communicate()[0], extension
        print(res)
        #return res
        exit()
```

I'm getting the result like

> (b'', 'doc')

Comment: Just to make sure: have you checked if `antiword` could really read the file? It is a rather ancient piece of software from 2005, so having a file with extension `.doc`, in 2018, absolutely does not ensure that it can be read this way.

Comment: Can you pls tell how i can check it?

Comment: You visit the file's folder from command line, type `antiword xy.doc` and see what happens. If it does not work there, it will not work from Python either.

Comment: seems antiword is not there. I have tried to find antiword for windows but i could not get it. can you suggest other method to extract text from .doc file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read .doc file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001482/read-doc-file-with-python)