# Reading Docs in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make docs read in python and I am not getting any error, but it also doesn't show what is written in document.

```
from docx import Document

import os


file = open('C:\\Users\\hamza\\Desktop\\Python\\qwe.docx','r', encoding='utf8' )

document =(file.read())
file.close()
```

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001482/read-doc-file-with-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read .doc file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001482/read-doc-file-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install docx2txt`

```
from docx2txt import process
import os
path = r'C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\Python\qwe.docx'
text = process(path)

with open(os.path.basename(path) + '.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```