# How to run a Excel document through a Python program

Tags: python, excel, text-files, textblob

I am trying to run a few hundred Trip Advisor reviews through a Sentiment Analysis program (via textblob), so that it will read each review and provide a sentiment for it. The program already works in that you can type a sentence in and it will return the sentiment (i.e. positive, negative, neutral). I would like to run a excel document through the program without having to manually type in each review. Ideally, the program returns a sentiment on each review.....How do I do this?

This is the code I already have...

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import string

z = 10

poscounter = 0

negcounter = 0

neucounter = 0

totalsentences = 0

while z > 0:
    
y = input("Type your sentence ").lower()  
    y = y.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    y1 = TextBlob(y)
    sentCheck = y1.sentiment.polarity

    if y == "stop":
        
            print(f"Positive Sentiment: {(poscounter/totalsentences) * 100} %")
            print(f"Negative Sentiment: {(negcounter/totalsentences) * 100} %")
            print(f"Neutral Sentiment: {(neucounter/totalsentences) * 100} %")
            exit()
            
        
    xplitIt = y.split(" ")
    
    for something in xplitIt:
        if something == "crowded" or something == "busy" or something == "crowds" or something == "hate" or something == "hated":
            print("negative")
            sentCheck = -0.1
            break
            
            

    if sentCheck==0:
        print("neutral")
        neucounter+=1

    elif sentCheck>0 and sentCheck <=1:
        print("positive")
        poscounter+=1

    elif sentCheck == -0.1 or sentCheck < 0:
        negcounter+=1
        if sentCheck != -0.1:
            print("negative")
          
    totalsentences = totalsentences + 1
```

Comment: You read the file from disk, and feed the resulting string to your `Textblob` input.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries to read text from word documents. You can have a look at `textract` that was suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43135832/7947994).

The text you read will probably have multiple reviews that you have to split into a list of reviews (e.g. with python's `split()` function). You can then give each of these reviews as `y` into your algorithm.

How you have to process your input depends on the structure of your document. You should include an example in your question if you need further help.